# Media Query Stylesheets

Tags: media-queries

I have 2 different stylesheets for my website, one for desktops and one for phones and tablets with all `:hover` functions disabled. I tried to use the the bootstrap media query definitions, but the desktop will show on some high-end phones, how could I address it?

this is my definitions for now:

```
<!-- IPHONE 4-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="/styles-basic.css" />
<!-- IPHONE 5-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)" type="text/css" href="/styles-basic.css" />
<!-- PHONES E TABLETS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles-basic.css" media="screen and (max-width:979px)">
<!-- DESKTOP -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css" media="screen and (min-width:978px)">
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, your iPhone 4/5 media queries will also include alot of other phones with those pixel ratios. Secondly, what stylesheet will load for browsers that don't support media queries or those browsers that have their window < 978px?

The best way to handle the root of this problem (:hover rules for touch devices) is to just serve one stylesheet to every browser and tuck your hover rules behind feature detection, like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). [Get Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and include it in your `<head>`. Once it's loaded correctly tuck your :hover css rules behind `.no-touch` in your CSS and it will only apply to those browsers that don't have touch screens.